# Angular 4 routing - redirectTo with skipLocationChange

Tags: angular, routes

I have some routing module with its main path being set as: `/canvas`

```
const canvasRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "canvas", component: CanvasComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(canvasRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
    declarations: [],
    providers: []
})
export class CanvasRoutingModule {
}
```

In the application routing module I would like to have the redirection path set to the `/canvas` every time the root path is accessed. Currently the configuration looks as follows:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "", redirectTo: "/canvas", pathMatch: "full"
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
    declarations: [],
    providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

It works correctly and access to the `http://localhost:4201` is being redirected to the `http://localhost:4201/canvas`.

However, I do not want to have the `/canvas` path appended to the url after redirection. How can this be achieved? Is there for example a way, that I could apply the `skipLocationChange` parameter to this redirection as I am using it with the `router.navigate(... {skipLocationChange: true})`?

Comment: So, why are you trying to redirect? Isn't this enough to use `path: "", component: CanvasComponent` or `path: "", component: XXX, children: [{path: "", component: CanvasComponent}]`?

Comment: It will not be so clearly descriptive in my opinion. In some other parts of my code I'm routing to the canvas component using `routerLink='/canvas'` . If I change it to `routerLink=''` the statement will became not clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have resolved that problem by subscribing to the `router.events` in the `AppComponent` and manually navigating to the `canvas` path with `skipLocationChange` set to true.

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.router.events.subscribe(routerEvent => {
            if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
                if (routerEvent.url == "/") {
                    this.router.navigate(["canvas"], {skipLocationChange: true})
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it really neccessary to subscribe to the event? Wouldn't it be enough if you would just put this one line into the constructor: `this.router.navigate(["canvas"], {skipLocationChange: true});` IMHO this should be sufficiant. Additionally you get away with the fact that you (unneccessarily) test for the root url in _every_ NavigationStart event!

Answer (score 6):

A little bit late, but maybe it's helpful:

I had the same problem and managed to solve it by adding ExtraOptions when declaring Router.forRoot

Like this:

```
imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { initialNavigation : false }) ],
```

With this you avoid the initial navigation that sets /canvas to the URL.

After that you can continue using skipLocationChange.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: This should not be marked as the correct answer as [`legacy_disabled`, `legacy_enabled`, `true`, or `false` are not supported as valid values](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/c4becca0e4238640461c43567a6d3e16b8c5d3f3).