# Get URL that would be generated by router.navigate

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I'm wondering if there's a way to get the URL that **would be** generated by Angular's router when calling the `navigate` method.

For example:

`this._router.navigate(['browse'], { queryParams: { section: 'users', isActive: true } });`

might result in a navigation to `/browse#?section=users&isActive=true`

How can I get this route without performing the navigation or updating the URL in the browser?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at [`createUrlTree`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#createUrlTree):

```
this._router.createUrlTree(
    ['browse'], { queryParams: { section: 'users', isActive: true } });
```

The returned object, a [`UrlTree`](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlTree) has a `toString` function that should give you what you want.

You can see from the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.2.x/packages/router/src/router.ts#L1000) that `navigate` actually uses `createUrlTree` internally:

```
navigate(commands: any[], extras: NavigationExtras = {skipLocationChange: false}):
        Promise<boolean> {
    validateCommands(commands);
    return this.navigateByUrl(this.createUrlTree(commands, extras), extras);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This one works with both: hash (e.g https://site/#/user) and non-hash urls

```
public openInNewTab(router: Router, namedRoute) {
    let newRelativeUrl = router.createUrlTree([namedRoute]);
    let baseUrl = window.location.href.replace(router.url, '');

    window.open(baseUrl + newRelativeUrl, '_blank');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the selected answer to [Angular 4 routing - redirectTo with skipLocationChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109731/angular-4-routing-redirectto-with-skiplocationchange)
You can subscribe to your router navigate event and add the "skipLocationChange" parameter to avoid switching URL